# New responsa on releasing terrorists in exchange for hostages?

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, army-military-war, responsa

The State of Israel has over the years engaged in the exchange of terrorists and criminals in exchange for the release of hostages. This topic has prior been explored in posts such as [Q 10731](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/) and [Q 86771](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86771/releasing-terrorists-in-exchange-for-remains-of-past-victims)

In the context of the October 7th attack and the latest series of exchanges, have any *new* responsa been written and published on this topic? I am interested in seeing both those for and against.

Comment: I've not seen any responsa but I have seen videos from prominent halachic authorities if that works for you?

Comment: @Dov Though my preference is for more comprehensive statements/treatments (if they exist) I would nevertheless accept answers that include on the record statements in any format from the respective authorities.

Comment: For sure - it is pretty recent in the grand scheme of things

Comment: Simon Jacobson commented on it [here](https://youtu.be/dyAu_Flb1BY?feature=shared&t=1837)

Comment: @shmosel thank you

Comment: Found some halachic discussion [here](https://merkazanash.com/sites/default/files/753%20-%20Honoring%20Seforim.pdf), under the Way of Life section.

Answer (score 7):

Following on from our interaction in the comments.

[HaRav Asher Weiss](https://minchasasher.com/about/) shlita has a recording where he discusses the issues at length [here](https://minchasasher.com/shiur/uncategorized/exchanging-terrorists-for-hostages-in-halacha/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll be giving it a listen :)

Comment: No worries - he's phenomenal!

Answer (score 4):

**R Shlomo Aviner** discusses his position in this very recent [podcast interview](http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/11423-%E2%80%93-shiur-441-%E2%80%93-prisoner-exchange-in-halacha-hear-from-a-brother-of-one-of-the-hostages/) (starting at 33:28).

He is known to be against exchanging terrorists for hostages (see the paragraph starting "Prisoner swap deals in modern Israel" in [this relevant article](https://www.jpost.com/judaism/article-769384)).

If the topic is of interest to you, note the forthcoming book on the laws of war from R Shlomo Brody who wrote extensively on the topic: [Ethics of Our Fighters: A Jewish View on War and Morality](https://korenpub.com/products/ethics-of-our-fighters).

Comment: +10 for Ethics of Our Fighters. True, very true.

Comment: I'll be giving a listen to R. Aviner and checking out R. Brody's book, thank you for bringing it to my attention!